# sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter with zookeeper is not working when i use CompositeFileListFilter

Tags: spring-integration, apache-zookeeper, spring-integration-sftp

i have used sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter with zookeeper.but it is giving me exception   :  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$LsEntry cannot be cast to java.io.File.  I am using the following code

```
<int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter
    id="sftpAdapter" channel="receiveChannel"
    session-factory="cachingSessionFactory" 
    remote-file-separator="/" remote-directory-expression="'${ftpServerLoc}'" filter="compositeFilter"
    auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="${pollarInterval}"
        max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>

  <beans:bean id="compositeFilter"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
             <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter">
                 <beans:constructor-arg value="^.*\.(dat|DAT)$" />

            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                <beans:constructor-arg name="store"
                    ref="metadataStore" />
                <beans:constructor-arg value="" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter` should be `org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter`.

The one you have applies to `java.io.File`; the sftp version applies to `LsEntry` (Jsch's representation of the remote file).

Comment: but now i am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path string "/metaDataStore/.." caused by relative paths not allowed @27 exception.

Comment: i am  getting  org.springframework.integration.zookeeper.metadata.ZookeeperMetadataStoreException: Error while trying to set '..' as well

Comment: That's a completely different, unrelated, problem; I suggest you ask a new question and show the complete stack trace.